# Will statements after "return" keyword be executed?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, return

I'm C++ beginner, would like to know the impact of this scenario:

```
PCONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX GetConsoleInfo(void) {
    WaitForSingleObject(m_hSync);   // m_hSync is HANDLE to mutex created using CreateMutex()

    return m_pcsbi;    // m_pcsbi is of type PCONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX

    ReleaseMutex(m_hSync);      // <== will this line be executed?
}
```

Wonder will the [ReleaseMutex()] be executed?

Comment: Why don't you determine yourself with a test program?

Comment: Will statements *in* an `if (0) { .. }` be executed? In the same manner, [`return`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k68ktdwf.aspx) controls program flow. (Doesn't MSVC++ warn about that too?)

Comment: Whatever compiler you use, there should be a way for you to activate warnings; and among those warnings there should be one telling you that this code will *never* be executed.

Comment: In modern C++, we have a `<mutex>` header. It has a nifty `std::lock_guard` which automatically unlocks the mutex at the end of a scope (including function scope)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, after a return statement, the destructors of the scope Objects will be called and the program will exit the function.

```
int main() { //Step 1
   GetConsoleInfo(); //2

   return (0); //6
}

PCONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX GetConsoleInfo(void) { //3
    WaitForSingleObject(m_hSync); //4

    return m_pcsbi; //5

    ReleaseMutex(m_hSync);
}
```

Maybe you should do something like :

```
int main() {
   WaitForSingleObject(m_hSync);
   GetConsoleInfo();
   ReleaseMutex(m_hSync);
   return (0);
}

PCONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX GetConsoleInfo(void) {
    return m_pcsbi;
}
```

Comment: Nothing? The destructors get executed after the return. That adds beauty to the language.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer help me understand how this is being executed. (try to tick this answer but not allowed for another few minutes...) 
So, in order for the mutex to be released, I'll have to do this?:

WaitForSingleObject(m_hSync);
PCONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX p = m_pcsbi;
ReleaseMutex(m_hSync);
return p;

Comment: I'm thinking to called Wait...() function in my function because the person who called my function (GetConsoleInfo()) might not be aware that other thread might be changing the console info...

Comment: @tongko: Unfortunately, that is not sufficient. A mutex can protect a shared resource only if both users of that shared resource also use the same mutex. If the other party isn't aware that your code works on the console info, it won't be aware of your console info mutex either.

Answer (score 6):

There's no way to get to that code in your case. If you have a conditional `return` (e.g. `if (ptr==nullptr) return;` ) then there are of course conditions in which the return will be skipped. But an unconditional return will be the last of the statements executed.

However, [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) style cleanup does happen after `return`.

Comment: For a C++ beginner, term "RAII_style cleanup" may be a little bit unclear, don't you think? :)

Comment: @Spook True, but at the same time, it's at least easily searchable.

Answer (score 3):

In that specific scenario no. You need to release the mutex before leaving the function.

Answer (score 0):

No but you can have exceptions

example with if statement:

```
   PCONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX GetConsoleInfo(void) {
     WaitForSingleObject(m_hSync);   // m_hSync is HANDLE to mutex created using CreateMutex()


     //if(statement)
            return m_pcsbi;    // m_pcsbi is of type PCONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX
     //else
          ReleaseMutex(m_hSync);      // if the statement is false, it will skip return and execute this line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly where [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization#C.2B.2B_example) is needed, as implemented by [`std::unique_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock):

```
PCONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX GetConsoleInfo()
{
    static std::mutex m_hSync;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{m_hSync};

    return m_pcsbi;    // m_pcsbi is of type PCONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX

    // mutex is released implicitly here
}
```

Releasing a mutex is something that should be done automatically at end of scope, including as well cases where an exception is thrown (during [stack unwinding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_unwinding)). Only desctructors can be called at that point and `std::unique_lock`'s destructor exactly releases the mutex.